# Change opacity of the layer with range slider

Tags: openlayers, transparency-opacity

I want to change the opacity of the layer with a range slider (input type="range") when scrolling
here is my layer code in main.js:

```
const UnTiled = new ol.layer.Image({
            opacity:0.9,
            title:'UnTiled',
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                ratio: 1,
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/shomal/wms',
                params: {
                         'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                      "STYLES": '',
                      "LAYERS": 'shomal:geotiff_coverage',
                      "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                }
            
              })
              
            });
map.addLayer(UnTiled)
```

and here is range slider input code:

```
<input id="contrast" type="range" value="contrast" max="0.5" min="0" step="0.01"/>
```

I tried below code in main.js but error is Uncaught TypeError: UnTiled.values_.opacity is not a function :

```
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
                UnTiled.values_.opacity( $(this).val());
            });
```

UnTiled.values_.opacity gives me the value of the layer's opacity
pleas help me to change layer ("UnTiled") opacity with range slider input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading of docs helps sometimes: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Image-ImageLayer.html#setOpacity. I warmly recommend it.

Instead of trying to change internal value `UnTiled.values_.opacity`, which shouldn't be done, use `.setOpacity` method:

```
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
  UnTiled.setOpacity($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and advice to read docs. I put your code but a new error that occurred is [link](https://openlayers.org/en/v6.5.0/doc/errors/#64) that said opacity should be a number

Comment: The above code works for me, so you must be doing something differently.

Answer (score 0):

this code works well.$(this).val()) gives the string to us and the opacity value should be number. so we put it at parseFloat function to change it to float value

```
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
            UnTiled.setOpacity(parseFloat($(this).val())); 
        });
```

thanks @TomazicM for his helps in openlayers and web mapping he is wonderful in his way